# Picture with four intersecting lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, labels, graphs

I have the following picture:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

        \draw [<->,thick] (0,3) node (yaxis) [above] {$P$}
            |- (3,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$Y$};

        \draw (0,0) coordinate (a_1) -- (2,1.8) coordinate (a_2);
        \draw (0,1) coordinate (a_3) -- (2,2.8) coordinate (a_4);
        \draw (0,1.5) coordinate (b_1) -- (2.5,0) coordinate (b_2);
        \draw (0,2.5) coordinate (b_3) -- (2.5,1) coordinate (b_4);

        \coordinate (c) at (intersection of a_1--a_2 and b_1--b_2);
        \coordinate (d) at (intersection of a_3--a_4 and b_1--b_2);
        \coordinate (e) at (intersection of a_3--a_4 and b_3--b_4);
         \coordinate (f) at (intersection of a_1--a_2 and b_3--b_4);

        \fill[red] (c) circle (2pt);
        \fill[red] (d) circle (2pt);
        \fill[red] (e) circle (2pt);
        \fill[red] (f) circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What i want to do (and i do not know how to) is i want to label those red intersections, i want to draw arrows pointing from one point to the other and on the top of that i want to make them visually of the same length i.e. force them to have an end in more or less the same place (like in a rectangle). And i want to label them at the ends (in one case the top end in the other the upper one)

Here is a paint made sketch of what i want to have (with labels for red dots as well):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `intersections` library to calculate the intersection points of pairs of lines (or curves).

To add labels to the lines, simply use the `node` on a path.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \draw [<->,thick] (0,3) node (yaxis) [above] {$P$}
            |- (3,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$Y$};
  \draw[name path=A] (0,0) coordinate (a_1) -- (2,1.8) coordinate (a_2)node[right]{SRAS1};
  \draw[name path=B] (0,1) coordinate (a_3) -- (2,2.8) coordinate (a_4)node[right]{SRAS2};
  \draw[name path=C] (0,2.5) coordinate (b_3) -- (2.5,1) coordinate (b_4)node[right]{AD2};
  \draw[name path=D] (0,1.5) coordinate (b_1) -- (2,.3) coordinate (b_2)node[right]{AD1};

  \fill[red,name intersections={of=A and C, by=c}](c)circle[radius=2pt];
  \fill[red,name intersections={of=B and C, by=d}](d)circle[radius=2pt];
  \fill[red,name intersections={of=B and D, by=e}](e)circle[radius=2pt];
  \fill[red,name intersections={of=A and D, by=f}](f)circle[radius=2pt];

  \draw[-latex,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=5pt]([yshift=3pt]c)--([yshift=3pt]d);
  \draw[-latex,thick,shorten <=7pt,shorten >=2pt]([yshift=-3pt]f)--([yshift=-3pt]c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: i want to have SRAS1 longer (similar to what we have with AD) and if i e.g. wanted to have labels to points what should i do?

Comment: @mkropkowski: It's just a matter of changing the end coordinate of the SRAS1 curve from `(2,1.8)` to something like `(2.5,2.2)`.

Comment: ok and point labels? because when i use node they tend to overlap with arrows and they are red ( i mean labels)

Comment: @mkropkowski: Try to add positioning keys to `node`. For example, `node[above=3pt,text=black]{x}`, and in place of `above`, you could also use `below`, `left`, `right`, etc.